# Excel VBA worksheet_change event doesn't fully trigger with multiple cell copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below piece of code that I found for a very similar question/problem and I have been trying to alter to suit my needs. Essentially I want the code to update a change log every time a cell within the named range is changed. The current code works great for single pieces of data entry However the code doesn't carry out the Offset(0,-2) part of the array if multiple cells are pasted into the named range. The array does pull the rest of the data into the change log. Can anyone assist?

```
Dim RangeValues As Variant, E As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Change Log")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
  'sh.Unprotect "" 'it should be good to protect the sheet
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "Role", "From", "To", "Sheet Name")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 If Intersect(Target, Range("WENAMES")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = extractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                                'avoiding to trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                           'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                            'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
 For E = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(E)(0) <> TgValue(E)(0) Then
        sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).Value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(E)(1), Target.Offset(0, -2).Value, RangeValues(E)(0), TgValue(E)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
    End If

 Next E
 
 'sh.Protect ""
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        sh.Range(El(1)).Value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub
Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
            For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Try `Target.Offset(0,-2).Cells(1).Value`

Comment: Hi Black Cat. That brings the first offset value across but not any following ones. For instance if I paste three cells into the named range I'll only get the offset value of the target cell

Comment: `Target` in the Change event is a reference to the cell or cells that are changing.  If `Target.Count` is greater than 1 then you need to step through each cell in the Target range.

Comment: Sorry Darren I don't understand. Doesn't  For E = 0 To UBound(RangeValues) step through this?

Comment: You can change to `Cells(E+1)` then it step through the offsetted range.

Comment: Could you share the complete code from `Sub...` to `... End Sub`? What is the address (the shape) of `WENAMES`? Note that **unless you use VBA** to write to a worksheet, there is no way you could paste **to** a non-contiguous (multi-area) range i.e. `Target` will always be a single-area range and assuming `WENAMES` is a single-area range, so will the intersection.